# Difference between Ctrl + Z and Ctrl + C

Tags: c, gcc, eof, ctrl

As per my understanding Ctrl+Z means EOF, isn't it? When Ctrl+Z is passed in as an input in the following program;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
   int a;
   a = getchar();

   if(a == EOF)
       printf("Program Ended\n");

   printf("Finished");
   return 0;   
}
```

It prints;

```
Program Ended
Finished
```

which is totally reasonable.

But when Ctrl+C is passed in as an input, Why does it outputs;
Program Ended, and simply end the program? Wasn't it supposed to end the program without printing anything as per the code?

PS: I'm using gcc 6.3.0

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C#In_command-line_environments help? Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. I found this literally by putting `ctrl-c` into a search engine.

Comment: Does it still occur if you replace `printf("Program Ended\n");` by something else? Say `printf("This is a test\n");`?

Comment: depends on your platform. On my linux box ctrl+d makes the standard input as EOF.

Comment: it's the signal sent from the terminal and has nothing to do with the compiler

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is the effect of Ctrl-C on C++ Win32 console applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914613/what-exactly-is-the-effect-of-ctrl-c-on-c-win32-console-applications)

Comment: `Ctrl+Z` (`Ctrl+D` in Uni*x land) is caught by the Operating System and sent to your executable as a signal that there is no more data (as `EOF`). `Ctrl+C` is caught by the OS... and sent to your executable as a signal to terminate. Your executable does not ever see `Ctrl+Z` (`0x1A`) or `Ctrl+D` (`0x04`) or `Ctrl+C` (`0x03`)

Comment: other duplicates: [How to send EOF via Windows terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16136400/995714), [What is EOF in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1782080/995714), [Ctrl+Z behaviour in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45665230/995714)

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Be careful referring to Ctrl+Z. On a Linux system that sends SIGSTOP to your process. That is a signal that cannot be caught.

Comment: Upen, Try again with a `'\n'` --> `printf("Finished");` --> `printf("Finished\n");`   ( I suspect your buffer is not flushed on Ctrl-C)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl-C maps to the ASCII control character `ETX` (End-of-Text - 0x03), while Ctrl-Z maps to ASCII `EOF` (End-of-Text - 0x26).  There is also Ctrl-D for `EOT` (End-of-Transmission - 0x04).

Now what a particular platform does when either of these are occur in the the `stdin` stream is platform specific (and not C language or GCC specific).  However the *macro* `EOF` has integer value -1 (rather than ASCII value 0x03)

When your code is executed at https://onlinegdb.com/4bF8adsM4 :

- Ctrl-C : Program terminates immediately (causes SIGINT signal to terminate process)
- Ctrl-D : `a = -1`, `getchar()` returns immediately.
- Ctrl-Z : `a == '\n'` `getchar() returns after newline (i.e. Ctrl-Z is ignored).

On Windows, (with Microsoft C in my tests):

- Ctrl-C : `a = -1`, `getchar()` returns immediately, Program terminates *after* outputting `"Program Ended\n"` with exception "`Exception thrown at 0x7747B915 (KernelBase.dll) in scratch2.exe: 0x40010005: Control-C.`"
- Ctrl-D : `a == EOT`, `getchar()` returns after newline
- Ctrl-Z : `a == -1`, `getchar()` returns after newline

In the Ctrl-C case, the exception was shown in the debugger, in normal use (from the command line, nothing is reported).  When run from the command line, it actually output `"Finished\n"` as well.  It seems that the process termination is asynchronous to the I/O and program execution and the program can continue to run for some time before being terminated.  I added further text, and only some of it was output.  YMMV

Either way, on Windows, Ctrl-Z on `stdin` does trigger an EOF signal for the `stdin` stream, while in Unix/Linux, it is Ctrl-D.  In both cases Ctrl-C causes process termination by SIGINT, but on Windows at least, it is an asynchronous signal/exception, and the process may not terminate immediately. Also in Windows, the EOF after Ctrl-Z  is buffered until after newline, whereas in Unix/Linux, it aborts the input immediately.

Note that it is possible to implement a SIGINT signal handler to trap Ctrl-C to prevent process termination by that method (or handle it more elegantly).

All the other ASCII control characters have Ctrl-key mappings, what any particular platform does with these and `stdin` is also platform dependent.

Comment: Control-D does't get inserted in the stream.  Instead, it causes any "read line" request to return with however much text has been typed.  A zero-byte return is interpreted as indicating an end-of-file condition, but if one types one or more characters before typing control-D, the effect will be to make characters before the control-D available to `getchar()` immediately, without the buffer having to contain a newline character.

Comment: @supercat Useful clarification, if a little semantic.  An EOF (-1, not ASCII EOF) is returned by getchar(), so in that sense it is "as-if" it were inserted the stream, though I concede it is not technically precise.  The findings were empirically determined, not by technical reference.  I am not sure it matters much in this instance.

Comment: The distinction is important if a program is receiving input from a pipe or redirected file.  An operator may type control-D in the middle of a program's input, with the effect of causing one read-input request to return zero bytes without closing the stream, but a control-D received from a pipe or redirected file will simply appear as character code 4.

Comment: @supercat Yes, I will correct it when I am at a keyboard rather than a phone.  In the meantime your comment will suffice.  I merely meant that I'd did not make a material difference to the answer, not that there were not circumstances where it was necessary to be more precise.